Uniform on $(0,1)$ vs Uniform on $[0,1]$
I read many papers about probability integer transformation or copula. Regarding the probability integer transformation, some use $X  \sim U(0,1)$, and others use $X \sim U[0,1]$. What are the differences, and why do we use the latter notation?
For example, here:
"Realize that the range of any distribution function $F$ is $[0,1]$, which equals the domain of any random variable governed by $\text{Uniform}$(0,1)." from this link: here

For a quick intuitive answer, just ask your self what is $P(X\in{0}\cup{1})$ for $X\sim U[0,1]$? If you can see that it's $0$, then it should atleast intuitively satisfy your query as to why both are the same as far as distributions are concerned.

It would be nice to know the working definition of $X \sim U(0,1)$ versus $X \sim U[0,1]$. Does $X \sim U(0,1)$ mean $X$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$? Or does it also mean $X(\Omega) \subseteq (0,1)$?

There is no difference between the laws $U[0,1]$ and $U(0,1)$. To see this, we can prove that they are the same probability law by using characteristic functions: $\int_{[0,1]}e^{i\xi x}dx=\int_{(0,1)}e^{i\xi x}dx,\,\forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}$ because the set $[0,1]\setminus(0,1)$ has zero Lebesgue measure. Since their characteristic functions coincide, $U[0,1]\sim U(0,1)$.

Why not just look at the cumulative distribution function (CDF), which is more basic?

@Michael this approach holds in greater generality

In what way does this approach hold in greater generality?  You need a theorem to prove that two random variables with the same characteristic function have the same CDF. You need another theorem to show two random variables with the same CDF have the same distribution.

@Michael I was referring to the fact that ${e^{ix\cdot \xi}|\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d}$ is a measure-determining family on $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$. I also believe there are generalizations to more abstract spaces where we can define a Fourier transform - if I find good references I'll provide them

I didn’t downvote. But it may be related to my comment on CDF being more elementary. That comment somehow got more “likes” than 99.9% of my other comments on stackexchange. For an encore, I will restate my comment with a pun: The CDF is less complex  than the characteristic function. =)


The random variables $V$ and $W$ with $V\sim \mathcal U(0,1)$ and $W \sim \mathcal U[0,1]$ are not the same, but their laws coincide.

Here, I assume $V(\Omega)=(0,1)$ and $W(\Omega)=[0,1]$. If one assumes $V(\Omega) \subseteq (0,1)$ and $W(\Omega) \subseteq [0,1]$, in the above statment "are not the same" needs to be replaced by "may not be the same".
As both $V$ and $W$ have the same laws, they can be considered equivalent when working with law-invariant metrics, that is, those functionals $\rho(X)$ whose values only depend on the law of $X$, such as $\mathbb E(X)$, $\text{ess-sup} (X)$, cdf, mgf, or cf.
However, there are metrics such as $\text{sup} (X)$, that are not law-invariant for which the difference between $V \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$ and $W \sim \mathcal U[0,1]$ shows itself well.
For example, consider the probability space $$(\Omega=[0,1], \mathcal B([0,1]),\mu)$$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then, for
$$V(\omega)=\omega, \omega\in (0,1),\\ V(0)=V(1)=0.5$$
$$W(\omega)=\omega, \omega\in [0,1]$$
we have $$V\sim \mathcal U(0,1), W \sim \mathcal U[0,1],$$ for which
$$\color{blue}{\text{sup} (\lfloor V \rfloor)=0 \neq \text{sup} (\lfloor W \rfloor)=1}.$$

What is your definition of $X\sim U[0,1]$? Are you assuming $X(\Omega)\subseteq [0,1]$? Are you assuming $X(\Omega)=[0,1]$?

@Michael For
$X=\mathcal U(0,1)$ and $Y=\mathcal U[0,1]$, $X:\Omega \to (0,1)$ and $Y:\Omega \to [0,1]$. For example, consider the probability space $(\Omega=[0,1], \mathcal B([0,1]),\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then, define $$Y(\omega)=\omega, \omega\in [0,1]$$  $$X(\omega)=\omega, \omega\in (0,1),\ X(0)=X(1)=0.5,$$

Thanks. I think the definition clarification is needed since we might have $X(\omega)=2$ even though $X$ has a CDF uniform over $[0,1]$. However if $X:\Omega\rightarrow[0,1]$, the function is not necessarily surjective. So even in your definition of $U[0,1]$, we might have $X\sim U[0,1]$ but $X(\Omega)=(0,1)$ and so $\sup{\lfloor X(\omega)\rfloor  : \omega \in \Omega}=0$.
